# Deploy addin project with ppt slide within solution and include it in deployed folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, office-interop

I am trying to deploy my project having power point slide in solution exlorer. however after I build these it gives me an error as it does not find this @@.ppt file in bin debug. I used build action as content and copy to output directory as copy always but seems of no help. is there any other option for this

[image]

Below is my code where I am trying to copy shapes from ppt saved in solution explorer to current ppt now after i deploy since this ppt doesnt add with deployed files it cannot find ppt so it doesnt add shapes.

```
   PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

        String programfilesPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        //var filesPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(programfilesPath).ToString()).ToString());
        String fullPath = programfilesPath;

        string pptname = "Moons.ppt";

        String themePresentationPath = fullPath + pptname;
        // PowerPoint.Application ppapp2 = 
        var temporaryPresentation = ppApp.Presentations.Open(themePresentationPath, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
        PowerPoint.SlideRange ppslr = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange;
        int countlargest = ppslr.Shapes.Count;
        string shapecount = harveyballs.SelectedItem.Label.ToString();
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(shapecount);
        ppslr.Shapes.SelectAll();
        PowerPoint.ShapeRange ppShR = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange;
        ppShR[count + 1].Copy();
        temporaryPresentation.Close();
        PowerPoint.SlideRange ppslr2 = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange;
        ppslr2.Shapes.Paste();
```

Answer (score 0):

> it does not find this @@.ppt file in bin debug

The debug folder is used as an output when current configuration is set to Debug. Are you sure that you have the Debug configuration set in Visual Studio?

Comment: i am trying to copy the shapes form this @@.ppt folder within solution to current open powerpoint slide

Comment: What value does the themePresentationPath string contain?

Comment: D:\Project\PowerPointAddin_V1.0\PowerPointAddin_V1.0\bin\Debug\shape.ppt .So my ppt named shape.ppt contains some shapes which i want to open and copy these shapes to my powerpoint i am currently using

Comment: Do you get an exception on the end user PCs or your dev one?

Comment: i get it on end users pc

Comment: Well, in that case most probably you didn't include the file to the add-in installer. Is that the case?

Comment: when i deploy my project this gets saved as shape.ppt.deploy when i do build action as content but it doesnt run....